# Programatically Create Nodes with Body and Custom Fields

Tags: entities

I need to write a module that will fetch remote content via an API and store it as nodes. These nodes have custom fields defined within the module. I have already accomplished this by modifying the [Node Example Module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/node_example).

I can add nodes via the admin end with all the custom fields, but when I'm trying to programatically create the nodes from hook_install(), the body and custom fields are not saving.

The code for creating the fields is largely the same as the example I linked. Here's the function i'm using to create the nodes:

```
function sm_add_mashup_item_node($remoteId, $site, $text, $image, $time){

    $node = new stdClass();
    $node->type = 'rscg_mashup';
    node_object_prepare($node);

    $node->title = "My Awesome Title";
    $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
    $node->created   = time();
    $node->timestamp = time();
    $node->changed   = time();

    $node->status = 1;
    //$node->uid = 1;
    $node->promote = 1;
    $node->sticky = 0;
    $node->format = 3;
    $node->language = 'en';
    $node->revision = 0;


    $node->body[$node->language][0]['format'] = 3;
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = 'summary';
    $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'dfg sdgdfs gsdg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdgsdf';

    // Try to set your custom field
    $node->rscg_mashup_image_url[$node->language][0]['value'] = "Too many to count...";

    echo "\n Edited: \n";
    print_r(node_load(526));

    echo "\n Pre-Save: \n";
    print_r($node);


    $node = node_submit( $node );
    node_save($node);

    echo "\n Loaded: \n";
    print_r(node_load($node->nid));

    return;
```

I've tried countless variations of the above.

Here is the debug output from the function:

https://gist.github.com/agroff/1c2c22920c20e3775b0d

This is a screenshot of the field list.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: OK, what exactly happens? You tried, good, but what is wrong? What happens? And can you show a comparison of node object loaded from existing node, and object you are creating?

Comment: @Mołot, Thanks for reading my question. I have updated the function to include debug info and linked to a gist of that debug info. 

The issue is that manually edited nodes properly store and display the body and custom fields, while programmaticly created ones do not. I have no idea what is wrong. There are no errors or anything.

Comment: Have you tried saving the node without custom fields filled in? Maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Disable your module, uninstall it and then install it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using  like below

```
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['format'] = 3;
    $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['summary'] = 'summary';
    $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'dfg sdgdfs gsdg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdfg sdgsdf';

// Try to set your custom field
    $node->rscg_mashup_image_url[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "Too many to count...";
```

Comment: Hmm, I can't see how this is different from what I'm doing but I'll give it a shot anyways. At this point I'll try anything.

Comment: The difference is that you are setting $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; and then $node->language = 'en' which overwrites the previous :). So ideally when you set custom field use LANGUAGE_NONE directly and your $node->language still can be 'en'

Comment: Ahh, I didn't even realize I was overwriting it. That wasn't my intention at all. Let me fix. If this works i'll be so stoked.

Comment: I'm not positive if this was exactly what fixed it, but it seems to at least be a contributing factor. Answer accepted and thanks for your help.